# Ideal way to Secure Custom Application

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, web-services, claims-based-auth, wcf

We are developing an application which is going to do some CRUD operations for a couple lists and offer our customers to download files.

We are using REST services as well as Sharepoint Web Services.

we thought that if we could configure the claim based authentication with FBA, we can authenticate customers in our code by using FBA provider.

what we want to do is that we already configure the FBA, we want to authenticate our users via FBA.

what is the ideal way to approach this problem, I am sure some of you guys encountered such scenario.  where to start, where to go, we r not sure thou. if you could share your experiences, I would be thankful.

Any help and idea will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by how to secure the application? If you setup SharePoint to use FBA, then the user of the application have to provide a Username and password, which the app will send to SharePoint to get SAML token, this token then gives access based on security settings for this user in SharePoint.

Comment: @PerJakobsen thanks for the info. is there any particular service I should use to do this or It needs to be developed? For instance, if I use REST services in SharePoint, how I am going to pass this to token to Rest service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this article below helped a lot.
[FBA and Client object model](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5961.using-the-client-object-model-with-a-form-based-auth-site-in-sharepoint-2010-another-approach-en-us.aspx)